# How to use a clip-path background (full bleed) and margin:auto for centering

Tags: css

I rely on the using a wrapper to center most of my sites ala:

```
.wrapper {
   margin:auto;
   max-width: xxxpx;
}
```

Keeps things centered perfectly, BUT also clears the margins, which is causing my problems as I want to use a clip-path background to create a simple polygon background, which needs to go through the margins, like:

```
.wrapper {
   background-color: #ebeef2;
   clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 37% 0, 100% 10%, 100% 90%, 63% 100%, 0 90%);
}
```

How can I get all of the elements of my page centered without clearing the margins?

Every solution I've tried ends up with impossible to manage page centering of elements, or a cleared page margin.

Here is the full bleed clip path I want.

[image: Successful Polygon background made with a clip-path]

Here is the problem.

[image: Unsuccessful polygon background]

Here are codepens: [no margin](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100), [margin with busted clip-path](https://codepen.io/macbubb/pen/jOaBWXv)

Comment: By center do you mean horizontally or vertically. Also, what exactly do you want to do? You could add property (margin: 0 auto )just for centering the element inside a element

Comment: Also `padding` would work as well, and your background would natively come behind it.

Comment: horizontal centering and the same page margins of all elements of all, so they are equal width when the viewport is greater than a max-width

Comment: @Noam, what do you mean exactly by adding padding? I experimented with that in the codepen and didn't get a different result.

Comment: @innocent, thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work

Comment: What I'm suggesting, in it's simplest form, is removing both `margin` and `max-width` and instead add something like `padding: 0 calc((100% - 640px) / 2);`

Comment: @MacBubb I still don't get what you are trying to say what do you mean by "margins of all elements of all". 

Also, Since you set a max-wdith to the container the container will be restricted to that size and anything added inside it will generally follow that rule. So, I'm not getting what exactly you are having problems with centring as seen from your busted clip path codepen.

Comment: OK, I sorted it out. sorry if I didn't explain what I wanted quite clearly enough. Here is the working codepen if you want to see exactly what i was looking for. I appreciate you all taking the time to help! https://codepen.io/macbubb/pen/jOaBWXv